# Error importing data from CSV with OpenRowset in SQL Server - Mysterious value of "S7"

Tags: sql-server, csv, openrowset

I have a file dump which needs to be imported into SQL Server on a daily basis, which I have created a scheduled task to do this without any attendant. All CSV files are decimated by ',' and it's a Windows CR/LF file encoded with UTF-8.

To import data from these CSV files, I mainly use `OpenRowset`. It works well until I ran into a file in which there's a value of "**S7**". If the file contains the value of "**S7**" then that column will be recognized as datatype of numeric while doing the `OpenRowset` import and which will lead to a failure for other alphabetic characters to be imported, leaving only NULL values.

This is by far I had tried:

1. Using IMEX=1: `openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0','text;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes;`
2. Using text driver: `OpenRowset('MSDASQL','Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);`
3. Using `Bulk Insert` with or without a format file.

The interesting part is that if I use `Bulk Insert`, it will give me a warning of unexpected end of file. To solve this, I have tried to use various row terminator indicators like '0x0a','\n', '\r\n' or not designated any, but they all failed. And finally I managed to import some of the records which using a row terminator of ',\n'. However the original file contains like 1000 records and only 100 will be imported, without any notice of errors or warnings.

Any tips or helps would be much appreciated.

Edit 1:
The file is ended with a newline character, from which I can tell from notepad++. I managed to import files which give me an error of unexpected end of file by removing the last record in those files. However even with this method, that I still can not import all records, only a partial of which can be imported.

Comment: So what actually *is* your rowterminator? \n or \r\n? Does your file end in a newline character?

Comment: Ok, if I use bulk insert, then the only working rowterminator will be ",\n". However even with this rowterminator that some file will come with a warning of unexpected end of file or only some of the records can be imported. Doing it with openrowset will import all records if there is no value as 'S7'.

Comment: The file needs to end with a row terminator otherwise the last row won't be imported.

Comment: @TT. The file actually end with a row terminator, which I can confirm that with it opened with Notepad++ and to see a CR LF label at the end of last row.

Comment: SQL server doesn't handle utf8 well, can you convert to utf16?

Comment: @Neock Edit1 at the bottom, reads: _The file is not ended with a newline character_

Comment: @HoneyBadger，@TT. Sorry I made a mistake, those files actually ended with newline character. They're Windows CRLFs. Ok now if there's any way to handle openrowset for importing csv and assume all columns to be string instead of assuming they are numbers it would be great.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I would rather not to modify any of those files. It is because those files are data dump from 3rd party and immediately after importing into SQL Server they are required to transfer to another place where further processing will be taken.

Comment: Openrowset just does what the driver tells it to do. Unfortunately the jet / ace / text drivers are kinda useless. Especially the completely dumb IMEX thing. I usually end up importing the text file into a single `VARCHAR(4000)` column (using Bulk Insert) and then shred it into seperate columns myself. This will also help you understand whatever issue you are currently having. In a file using `,` seperators, it's entirely possible that a field contains an extra comma, messing everything up. I suggest you pursue the BULK INSERT approach and resolve the unexpected end of file issue